# User Profile Sync is not currently provisioned

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service

Our site was hit by a major disaster whic reduced our 6 server sharepoint farm to 2 servers.  I have recovered the entire environment with the exception of the User Profile Service.

Whenever I attempt to start the service it says it is starting for about 5 minutes then eventually goes back to Stopped.  The sync service shows as not provisioned

I have attempted various fixes from around the web including:
[The Autofixer](https://sharepointbjorn.com/2014/06/25/user-profile-synchronization-autofixer/) which finds no problems yet says it is unable to start it:

[image: auto fixer messages]

I have also deleted and recreated the provisioning service but this made no difference.

Could someone point me in the direction of a way to troubleshoot this?

## Update

Thanks to input from you guys I have actually manage to ge the error up:

```
UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS: Failed to configure MIIS post database, will attempt during next rerun. Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: ERR_CONFIG_DB 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.Synchronization.ILMPostSetupConfiguration.ValidateConfigurationResult(UInt32 result) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.Synchronization.ILMPostSetupConfiguration.ConfigureMiisStage2() 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SetupSynchronizationService(ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance profileSyncInstance).
```

Of the possible causes listed on this page https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2015/06/16/err_config_db-while-starting-the-upa-synchronization-service-in-sharepoint-20102013/

none seem to apply to my situation.  Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: What errors does the ULS logs record during the attempt to start the synchronization?

Comment: You need to look at Harbar, and the guide works as well for 2010, 2013 and 2016 environment: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

Comment: @moe - can't see anything in logviewer.  But I'm not sure what I am looking for!

Comment: @BennySkogberg - thanks, now that looks like a useful guide.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Using the technique herehttp://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx#ups12 means I can now see some interesting stuff in the log.  Will work through those.

Comment: Lobsterpants, please keep us updated with the errors and solution you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a call with Microsoft and their Sharepoint support guys found the problem pretty quickly.

It seems I needed to install the SQL NAtive CLient R2 on all the servers in the farm.  This was a bit of a shock as it was all working before so I thought all the prerequesits would be on there.

Once that was installed it all started perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your User profile synchronize service is started. Else run the below command

$serviceInstance. = Get-SPServiceInstance | Where { $_.TypeName -like "User Profile Synchronization Service "}
$serviceInstance.Unprovision()

Then manually start User Profile Synchronization Service from CA> application Mangement> Manage services on server

Then enter farm account password and start.
Make sure your user profile service had farm account as administrator for that CA> Application management> Manage service application select user profile application click on administrator on ribbon then give full access to farm admin account.

After starting sync service make sure fore front management service is started in services.

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2014/01/13/how-to-start-user-profile-synchronization-service-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx